# Animating text, adding colour to a spefic word in javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an issue with getting the animation to have a specific colour of text on a particular word.
The text I have animated is working fine for the animation, but I need the second word to be in a different colour (currently the words are creative thinking, I need the thinking in a different colour).

I'm using CSS and JavaScript to achieve the desired animation effect, based on Moving letters.
https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#6

I am currently at a loss as to how to achieve this at present, I have tried to modify the script and I am not sure how else to go about adding colour to the second word.

Here is the code:

```
.ml6 {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 900; 
  font-size: 3.3em;
}

.ml6 .text-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 0.2em; 
  padding-right: 0.05em; 
  padding-bottom: 0.1em;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.ml6 .letter {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1em;
}
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animejs/2.0.2/anime.min.js"></script>
```

```
// Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml6 .letters');
textWrapper.innerHTML = textWrapper.textContent.replace(/\S/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>");

anime.timeline({loop: true})
.add({
  targets: '.ml6 .letter',
  translateY: ["1.1em", 0],
  translateZ: 0,
  duration: 750,
  delay: (el, i) => 50 * i
})
.add({
  targets: '.ml6',
  opacity: 0,
  duration: 1000,
  easing: "easeOutExpo",
  delay: 1000
});
```

Any assistance on this would be appreciated.

Comment: change the color with css

Comment: Ail, I've tried but for some reason its not working. I think it might be the divi template on wordpress that is overriding the custom css

Comment: check if !important works also check that your targeting is right

Comment: Tried using !important and still no colour. I'm at a loss as to how to make the text be in a different colour

Comment: I added in a new css class called m20 to the  // Wrap every letter in a span
var textWrapper = document.querySelector('.ml6 .letters .m20');

But it breaks the animation, I get the colour now, but not the proper animation, only the second part is animated correctly